# Do I have to define all methods in Pundit policy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a Project policy that only super or admin can have access to.
It looks like this now:

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def index?
    super_or_admin?
  end

  def new?
    super_or_admin?
  end

  def create?
    super_or_admin?
  end

  def update?
    super_or_admin?
  end

  def show?
    super_or_admin?
  end

  def super_or_admin?
    user.role.name == 'superadmin' or user.role.name == 'admin'
  end
end
```

Is it possible to have pundit automatically apply `super_or_admin?` to all the routes instead of defining each of them manually?

Comment: Not sure about Pundit, but if all those methods are doing is just calling `super_or_admin?` you could just alias them all: `alias :index? :super_or_admin?` and reduce some code that way

Answer (score 3):

You can define your policy like this:

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def initialize(user, record)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError.new(policy: 'project') unless super_or_admin?
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    true
  end

  def super_or_admin?
    user.role.name == 'superadmin' or user.role.name == 'admin'
  end
end
```

So it will check permissions on initialization. Defining `method_missing` in this case is necessary, because otherwise you will receive `NoMethodError` for action-specific methods (`create?`, `update?`, etc.). But you don't need to define them, because you check permissions in `initialize` method, that will be called anyway.

Then, if you need authorization in all actions, in your controller or it's ancestor you can define:

```
include Pundit

def authorize_project
  authorize :project
end
```

And use `before_action` callback like this:

```
before_action :authorize_project
```